# IE Session.Abandon()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

IE seems a bit buggy when it comes on Abondoning the session. This is the whole code thats get executed:

```
Protected Sub logout_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session.Abandon()
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
End Sub
```

It redirects to login.aspx but when i change the url to default.aspx its get in without checking it. In all the other browsers it doesnt and get you redirected because of the following code:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If (Session("Naam") Is Nothing) Then
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
Else
      Label1.Text = "Welkom " + Session("Naam").ToString()  
End If
    End Sub
```

Is there any reason that IE doesnt abandon the session?

note/*/*
I am not using log-incontrol what so ever

Comment: Is it because of cache of the page ?

Comment: Nope cleared my cache several times, but the weird thing, I have a dropdownlist with a autopostback ( like refreshing the page) it does redirect to the login.aspx. so it knows that there is no one logged in but it still says: Welcome (username)

//EDIT//

Found something weird to, default.aspx is the only which I can acces then, anyother page like contact.aspx cant be reached and redirects me to login.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling/removing the autopostback  and then re-test your page. I would guess that the autopostback is somehow keeping your session data active,maybe its being used in the postback? therefore all instance's dont get abandoned?.

## Edit

When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the script commands on the current page have been processed. This means that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web pages.

For example, in the following script, the third line prints the value Mary. This is because the Session object is not destroyed until the server has finished processing the script.

```
<% 
  Session.Abandon  
  Session("MyName") = "Mary" 
  Reponse.Write(Session("MyName")) 
%>
```

If you access the variable MyName on a subsequent Web page, it is empty. This is because MyName was destroyed with the previous Session object when the page containing the previous example finished processing.

The server creates a new Session object when you open a subsequent Web page, after abandoning a session. You can store variables and objects in this new Session object.

The above is from the MSDN website.

Which all means that somewhere your session object is being used AFTER you have abandoned it.

I normally use the same code block as you do to log a member out of a session.

```
Session.Abandon()
Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
```

with the same code in the global.asax or global.aspx file too.

Comment: Mhh oke, but what are the effects from it? Does it make it easier to hack? And why is this issue only for IE and not for chrome, ff etc? Does IE handle different? 

+1 for the awsome explenation!

Comment: Having the same code (SESSION.ABANDON and RESPONSE.REDIRECT in the global.asax/global.aspx means that when you EXECUTE the SESSION.ABANDON in your logout page, that statement, forces program execution to jump to the Session_OnEnd EVENT in the global.asax/global.aspx file because the event has occurred (the session has ended). INSIDE the SESSION_ONEND procedure the user is RESPONSE.REDIRECT(ed) to the non member page home/login, thereby STOPPING any further script statements to be executed on the initial page (logout.aspx), I assume thats how it works. LOGOUT page should be strictly for logout